# javascript: change style of element after scrolling past element

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a button and I want it to become a sticky notification bar after scrolling past that element (so when it disappears). When a visitor scrolls back to or above the position of the button the reverse process should occur. I assume it should happen by changing the style of the element. Any heads up?

Comment: use listener to scroll, and pageX to know if passed $(elm).position().top as you want

Comment: Heads up: Search for detect scroll past

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I worked it out.